# Sliding Update Of UIView

Tags: xcode, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uiview, ios6

I'm looking to update my UIView's values the same way that the iOS' music app does when one uses the next song button. By this I mean having the UIView update slide in from the left when a user clicks last song button and sliding in from the right when a user clicks next song button. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the custom control DYNavigationController
https://github.com/dyang/DYNavigationController

A tutorial to use the same is given at this link http://iappexperience.com/post/23551184719/chromeless